# ajaxslt unable to get node using XPATH

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I am using the ajaxslt javascript library.(http://code.google.com/p/ajaxslt/) I am trying to get the node using XPATH

My XML is as follows:

```
  <page>
            <message>
              Hello World.
            </message>
          </page>
```

I am trying to use //page so that I can all nodes below page i.e. message node. When i try to print the same. I am getting only Hello World as output.

Following is the code snippet i used.

```
<script src="./js/xpath.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="./js/xpath_script.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`function showMessage(){
    var xml = document.getElementById('xml');
    var ctx = new ExprContext(xmlParse(xml.value)); 
    var expr = xpathParse("//page");
    var result = expr.evaluate(ctx);
    alert("res:"+result.stringValue());
}`

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Saravanan K

Answer (score 0):

**You must use:**

```
//page/message
```

this selects in general more than one `message` element. You need to iterate through the returned node-list and produce the string value of each selected `message` element.

Comment: Is there a way to get the node <message>Hello World</message> using xpath ajaxslt library?

Comment: @SaravananK, The XPath expression in my answer does exactly that, on the provided XML document. If your XML document is different, one cannot give you an XPath expression that selects a particular node, without first seeing that new XML document. My *guess* is that in the document that you haven't shown to us, there are many `message` childen of the top element `page`. To select the node that you requested in your comment, use: `/*/message[.='Hello World']` This selects any `message` element whose string value is `"Hello world"` and that is a child of the top element `page`.